# Error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, requirejs, magento2

When I am using jQuery in phtml file, I get error in console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".
And my jQuery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
            alert("Hello world");
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance ...!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript error : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723462/javascript-error-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: I didn't understand @ventiseis

Comment: `require` isn't a standard `js` function. [There seems to be another way to include libs in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97184/how-to-use-jquery-library-in-magento-2), but I'm surely no `magento` expert. _Furthermore, you don't need `jquery` for an `alert`_. What do you want to do anyway?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some Error While generating Js in your magento setup:

Please execute `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

(to remove static, generation, someother temporary files),

then `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and see if this error still happens With Following Simple Jquery Alert.

```
require(["jquery"],function($){
     $(document).ready(function(){
          alert('Jquery Loaded');
     })
 })
```

Thankx

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just 
blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sure, @Rob I've Updated the Answer.