# I can't use a JS script in my HTML with Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

Good afternoon !

I have develop a node js server and now I would like to display a html file that contains a Vue script which load a data thanks to another method written in another JS file.

But when I try to load my html file on my browser, I have this error :
**ReferenceError: NbRequest is not defined**

My html :

```
<div id="PRISME_data">
    Le nombre de requête est de  : {{ nb_request }}<br>
    <button v-on:click="change">change</button>
</div>

<script>    
    let app = new Vue({
       el:'#PRISME_data',
       data: {
          nb_request: 0
       },
       methods: {
          change: function() {
          changeNbRequest()
          }
       }
     });

     changeNbRequest = function() {
     var timer = setInterval(function() {
           app.nb_request = new NbRequest().returnRandomNumber();
        }, 5000);
     }
 </script>
```

And my other JS file (NbRequest.js) :

```
var cron = require('cron');
var fs = require('fs');

class NbRequest {
    returnRandomNumber() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 500);
    }
}
```

Of course I have added the script definition :

```
<script src="../NbRequest.js"></script>
```

I don't know if I am really clear, but can you help me ?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading your class after your Vue variable.

Try putting `<script src="../NbRequest.js"></script>` first and then

```
<script>    
    let app = new Vue({
          .....
```

Comment: ok I have tried, and now I have this error : ** ReferenceError: require is not defined **

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723462/javascript-error-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined